# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM cannot find repository

Tags: java, git, maven, pom.xml

The company gave me a project on data compressor, I have to run [the project](https://github.com/teevrdatainc/dataxlrator) and reduce it's compression ratio.

To run the project i downloaded all the repositories using maven. But the POM file  is giving an error as:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.influxdb:influxdb-java:jar -> version 1.5 vs 2.4 @ line 254, column 16
>   [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: log4j:log4j:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 1.2.17 @ line 264, column 22
>   [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 3.6.1 @ line 302, column 18
>   [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for teevr-apps-dataxlrator:teevr-dataxlrator:1.1.15: Failure to find teevr-apps:parent-root:pom:1.0.0 in https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/californium/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo.eclipse.org has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 10
>    @ 
>   [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR]   The project teevr-apps-dataxlrator:teevr-dataxlrator:1.1.15 (E:\Ubuntu\dataxlrator-master\dataxlrator\pom.xml) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for teevr-apps-dataxlrator:teevr-dataxlrator:1.1.15: Failure to find teevr-apps:parent-root:pom:1.0.0 in (same link as above) was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo.eclipse.org has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 10 -> [Help 2]
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

i ran this project as maven build in eclipse neon.

This is my first question on this site so please forgive me for the inconvenience caused in analyzing my problem.

I think you would find every thing in the project link itself but if I missed something please let me know.

Comment: may i ask you why you deleted my git hub

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated the dependencies in your POM, leave only one for each.

```
org.influxdb:influxdb-java
log4j:log4j
org.apache.commons:commons-math3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i removed all the duplicated dependencies still it shows the same error , did you try to run the dataxlarator that is the main class in endpoint.java, was the dataxlalarator working for you if yes please let me know how thanks.